# Installing cucumber in windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am using Rails 2.3.5, ruby version 1.8.7, rubygems version is 1.3.6 and windows operating system. I am trying to install cucumber but installation fails with make error and searched and found a solution from this website

http://mikewagg.blogspot.com/2009/06/installing-cucumber-on-windows.html

But this too failed.

**Error Log:**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cucumber:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for re.h... no 
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Successfully installed win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32

1 gem installed

Installing ri documentation for win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32...

Installing RDoc documentation for win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32...
```

Can anyone direct me to install? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This blog doesn't exist now: http://mikewagg.blogspot.com/2009/06/installing-cucumber-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to work with Rails on windows in [CYGWIN](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Have installed devkit and installed cucumber got working fine :) . Thanks for your quick reply.